# TypeError: setProperty() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given error while using in pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

Pyttsx3 module error
when I run this it gives me error. But I want to have female voice to be moderated ..how can I do it
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

```
engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty(voices[1].id,'rate',178)


def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
    speak("Hello welcome to Shimla Bank")
```

Comment: https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html - setProperty required 2 parameters (name and value). You give 3.

Comment: If it supports it, you probably want `voices[1].setProperty('rate',170)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```py
egnine.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty("rate", 178)
```